# Unable to delete hidden files using FOR command

Tags: for-loop, command, dos, del

I am trying to put together a command that will delete all hidden and non-hidden .tmp files under all sub-directories from a deep file structure using 8.3 short file names.

I have been experimenting with a simple test directory called `c:\dl\test1234567890` using the following command:

```
for /r c:\dl\test1234567890 %Q in (*.tmp) do del /A "%sfQ"
```

I was hoping the `/A` would delete ALL hidden and non-hidden .tmp files but it only seems to delete non-hidden files. Hidden files remain. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
attrib /s -h "d:\wherever\whatever\*.tmp"
del /s "d:\wherever\whatever\*.tmp"
```

The first command un-hides the files, the second delets them **(Use with extreme caution)**

You may also want to add `-s` and possibly `-r` to the list of switches in the `attrib` command (remove "system" and "read-only" attributes)

Comment: Thanks mate, but I dont think this will help me with vey long file paths which is why I was hoping to use 8.3 short names and is the reason why i have had to employ the for command and the s in %sfQ